# Command line prompt to unpin folder from file explorer quick access

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-explorer, sharepoint

A sharepoint path that i try to access via file explorer keeps crashing my file explorer. Is there a command line prompt to unpin (delete shortcut???) from quick access? Anyone heard of sharepoint-file explorer issues like this?

Comment: What happens when you try doing his from safemode?

Comment: From my point of view, If I was having this kind of problem.  I wouldn't look for a work around, I would re-install windows. I know it's extreme, but when something that's a simple as this start giving you problems, other things are going to start creeping up aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the file to delete to remove all quick access links. Seemed to restore to a previous version from before I had my profile rebuilt (work comp).

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-quick-access-reset-pinned-shortcuts-stuck-not-working-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is a network share causing the problem: disconnect entirely from the network (enable Airplane Mode, unplug Ethernet cable), kill File Explorer (it should restart automatically), unpin the problematic/unwanted pinned Quick Access shortcut, reconnect to the network.